# Word or phrase describing relationship based on care/responsibility

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to know if there's a more succint way of saying the following:

*The adult who the infant is under the care of*

As an example, I am writing acceptance criteria for my software application:

> Requests for the check-in status of an infant-on-lap will return the
>   check-in status for the adult who the infant is under the care of.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: [In loco parentis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_loco_parentis) is fairly widely understood.

Comment: I would steer clear of *in loco parentis*. Firstly, it is rarely used to refer to anything except the legal obligations of educational institutions. And, even when it is used in the context of a single individual, it refers not to that individual as a person, but rather to the doctrine by which a court may formally establish that person as a legally recognized guardian of a minor child. Finally, it is an unfamiliar term for most persons, who may misapprehend some sort of legal standing pertains to your criteria.

Comment: @PhilSweet I'm not altogether happy with *in loco parentis*. For one thing it is not a noun, which I understood the OP was seeking. You couldn't for example say *I left Jonny with "in loco parentis"*. Another thing is that it has a specific legal sense, and comes in degrees. If I am a child-minder I have certain aspects of *in loco parentis* e.g. I can prevent the child strangling the neighbour's cat. But more advanced elements of *ILP* e.g. deciding what the child is allowed to eat, may not be devolved upon me.

Comment: “The adult accompanying the infant” is great as long as it is well defined & understood by all parties to the inquiry as meaning “the adult whose ticket is associated with the infant,” but in cases where the infant is accompanied (in layman’s terms) by a couple, to avoid false negative or false positive returns to an anxious grandmother who knows her daughter is accompanying the child (& can’t remember her son-in-law’s name!-joke), you might consider the following:  … “the accompanying adult whose ticket is associated with the infant” … or “the accompanying adult named on the [Infant] SSR.”

Comment: Now that we have a concrete example, I agree, it's not the right term for an air travel notice. It would imply a recognition of status and due diligence far beyond what common carriers are responsible for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase it just as the airlines do:

> A request for the check-in status of an infant-on-lap will actually
>   return the status of the adult accompanying the infant.

Comment: That's great - accompanying is the right word for this. Incidentally the software is for an airline ;)

Answer (score 1):

A recognised term in the UK is ***child minder***. In fact Social Services employ *registered child minders* for the purpose. (People who have themselves been vetted as suitable, with appropriately equipped and safety-approved homes)

In any event *the adult who the infant is under the care of* if not expressed simply as *child minder*, might be better expressed as *the adult in whose care the infant is placed*.

Comment: _Child minder_ is a profession, and would only apply to people who were employed to look after the child, so may be too specific for this purpose. Schools tend to use "parent/guardian".

Comment: @y6nH I accept what you say, but *child-minder* gets a good deal of informal use too - in Britain.